# C# Sequential File.Copy or FileStream kill server

Tags: c#, file, server, copy, remote-access

I have a big problem with copying files. When I copy files by File.Copy or FileStream, executing code kill my server. I copied ten files from remote directory to temp dir. The biggest file have around 20MB and cause error

At first I tried File.Copy(), when I run code, server collapsed.

```
foreach (string file in customerFiles)
{                    
    File.Copy(file, tempOnFile);
}
```

Same server collapsed happened when I tried this code in foreach:

```
byte[] buffer;
FileStream fileReader = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);                    
try
{
    int bufferSize = (int)fileReader.Length;
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int count, sum = 0;
    while ((count = fileReader.Read(buffer, sum, bufferSize - sum)) > 0 )
    {
        sum += count;
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    fileReader.Flush();
    fileReader.Close();
}

//Write
string fileOnTemp = pathToTemp + fileName;
FileStream fileWriter = new FileStream(fileOnTemp, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
try
{  

    fileWriter.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    fileWriter.Flush();
    fileWriter.Close();
}
```

Please Help! Thank you,
Michal

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: I didn't get any exception. None exception is catched. I am working on server via VMware. When I run code, server collapsed. After that I must do hard server restart.

Code works well in debug, when I step the code slowly.